# Is it legal to pass pointer without length as a destination into memcpy?

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy

I would like to know can I use char pointer without length as a destination in memcpy.
Example: I want to copy data from char array of defined length, with certain size into another array, but I would like to define it as a pointer without certain size.

```
char * ptr_1;
char arr[4] = "Data";
memcpy(ptr_1, arr, 4); // IS it allowed to do this?
```

Comment: What is your intent? Where exactly do you want to copy the data to? This is something you have to specify in order go get something useful.

Comment: The only thing you can say about `ptr_1`, is that it's an uninitialized variable which can contain an address of a memory location, and the data at this address must be interpreted as a single `char` when you try to read it. You can either assign it an address of a static array, or an address of a local (temporary) array (which has a limited lifetime), or assign it an address returned by a call to `malloc` (which is allocated on the heap and released by calling `free`). Since writing to an unspecified random address is a bad thing, you must initialize it in one of these 3 ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ptr_1` is a pointer and pointing to anything and doing `memcopy` on random location leads to undefined behavior.

pointer must be assigned to a valid address before `memcopy` is called.

Like this,

```
char buf[5];
char * ptr_1 = buf;
char arr[5] = "Data";
memcpy(ptr_1, arr, 5); //As string is null terminted need to conside `/0` char as well
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do that. If you do that, it would invoke undefined behavior as the address pointed by `ptr_1` is in determinant and you don't own it. Moreover, you haven't allocated any memory to hold the contents from `arr`.

You can either allocate a static storage for copying the result or allocate a storage dynamically. The prototype for `memcpy()` is

```
void *memcpy( void *dst, void const *src, size_t length );
```

So for a statically allocated address, you can do something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char temp[5];
    char values[] = "Data";
    memcpy( temp, values, 4 );
    temp[4] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", temp);
    return 0;
}
```

or with a dynamically allocated storage location pointed by `ptr` capable of holding 4 `char` bytes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 4

int main(void) {
    char *ptr;
    char values[] = "Data";
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * (SIZE+1)); 
    if ( ptr == NULL ) return; 
    memcpy(ptr, values, SIZE);
    ptr[SIZE] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Though the prototype for `memcpy()` defines the use of `void *` for the source and destination types, the C standard does not mandate it. Pointers can be converted between any type to `void *` and vice versa. That is the reason why we don't case the result of `malloc()` also.

You always need to allocate storage to include  a null character at the end. If you initialize the array with a empty length specifier, i.e. as `values[]`, the compiler automatically allocates storage to include a null character at the end. For a library function like `printf()` to print a string, it would ideally expect the string to be terminated with the null character at the end. Absence of it might trigger undefined behavior as it doesn't know where the end of string is ( the null character). So in the both the cases ensure the last byte of the string is the null character constant.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", temp);` invokes UB. No NUL

Comment: A more foolproof way would be `char temp[sizeof values]; memcpy(temp, values, sizeof values );`, avoids these darn off-by-one errors.